# Cast void to typedef (best practice)

Tags: c++

What would be the best practice to cast a void array to a typedef?

This is how I am currently doing it :

```
typedef struct {
    int16_t left,right;
} SampleStereo16;

void *buffer[100000]; // data buffer
SampleStereo16* sample;

// insert something here that writes to the buffer

sample = (SampleStereo16*) buffer;
```

This seems to work fine but somehow I have the feeling there is a better way.
I was also wondering if there is way to have the sample array and the buffer share the same memory (now they each use their own memory).

Here is the full code I am currently working on :

```
#include "fmod.h"
#include "fmod.hpp"
#include "fmod_errors.h"
#include "wincompat.h"
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
    int16_t left,right;
} SampleStereo16;

void ERRCHECK(FMOD_RESULT result)
{
    if (result != FMOD_OK)
    {
        printf("\nFMOD error! (%d) %s\n", result, FMOD_ErrorString(result));
        if (result != FMOD_ERR_FILE_EOF)
            exit(-1);
    }
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FMOD::System     *system;
    FMOD::Sound      *sound;
    FMOD_RESULT       result;
    unsigned int      version;

    int channels;
    int bits;

    unsigned int         lenbytes; // length in bytes read
    void                 *buffer[1000000]; // data buffer
    unsigned int         *read; // number of bytes actually read
    unsigned int        position; // offset in PCM samples
    unsigned int         samplesread; // number of PCM samples read
    unsigned int        samplesbuffer; //
    unsigned int        cueposition;

    SampleStereo16*     sample;


    /*
        Create a System object and initialize.
    */

    result = FMOD::System_Create(&system);
    ERRCHECK(result);

    system->getVersion(&version);

    result = system->getVersion(&version);
    ERRCHECK(result);

    if (version < FMOD_VERSION)
    {
        printf("Error!  You are using an old version of FMOD %08x.  This program requires %08x\n", version, FMOD_VERSION);
        getch();
        return 0;
    }

    result = system->setOutput(FMOD_OUTPUTTYPE_ALSA);
    ERRCHECK(result);

    result = system->init(32, FMOD_INIT_NORMAL, 0);
    ERRCHECK(result);

    result = system->createStream("/home/dpk/Dropbox/Music/Will Smith - Miami.mp3", FMOD_SOFTWARE, 0, &sound);


    result = sound->getFormat(0, 0, &channels, &bits);
    ERRCHECK(result);

    printf("channels : %d   bits : %d \n", channels, bits);

    if (channels!=2 and bits!=16)
    {
        printf("File must be stereo (2 channels) 16 bits \n");
        exit(-1);
    }

    lenbytes = sizeof(buffer);
    samplesbuffer = lenbytes / channels / ( bits / 8 );
    position = 0;
    cueposition = 0;

    do
    {
        result = sound->seekData(position);
        ERRCHECK(result);

        printf("Reading block : %u  ",position);

        result = sound->readData(&buffer, lenbytes, read);
        ERRCHECK(result);

        samplesread = *read / channels / ( bits / 8 );

        sample = (SampleStereo16*) buffer;

        printf("number of PCM samples read : %u \n", samplesread);


        for(unsigned int i=0; i<samplesread; i++)
        {
            if (cueposition==0 && ( abs(sample[i].left)>500 || abs(sample[i].right)>500 ) )
            {
                cueposition = position+i;
                printf("cue point : %u \n", cueposition);
            }
        }

        position += lenbytes / channels / ( bits / 8 );

    } while(samplesread==samplesbuffer);

    printf("\nExit\n");

    /*
        Shut down
    */
    result = sound->release();
    ERRCHECK(result);
    result = system->close();
    ERRCHECK(result);
    result = system->release();
    ERRCHECK(result);

    return 0;
}
```

I am also getting segmentation faults when increasing the buffer too much, but from what I have been able to find so far it seems to be a stack size limit.

Also feel free to comment on anything I am doing wrong, I just recently (last week) started C++ so I am pretty sure some things look bad in my code.

Comment: If you just started C++ last week, this is not the way to learn C++ and program C++ in 2013. You will learn a lot of bad habits that you will have to unlearn. If you want to try audio programming, I would take a look at SFML at http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.0/ It has an interface that looks more like what a C++ interface should have.

Comment: You can't have "an array of void". What you have is an array of void *pointers*, which is almost certainly not what you *want* or *meant to have*. And "a typedef" is not a type in C. It is a keyword used to create aliases for a type so you can refer to it by other names than its original one. What you want to cast to is a *struct*, not a typedef. :)

Comment: Your `unsigned int *read;` is not allocated and probably thats why you have seg fault. Use something like this instead `unsigned int read; result = sound->readData(&buffer, lenbytes, &read); samplesread = read / channels / ( bits / 8 );`. Why instead of void buffer you dont use `SampleStereo16 buffer[10000]; sound->readData(&buffer, 10000*sizeof(SampleStereo16), &read);`. This should work.

Comment: Just checked sfml, looks nice but the audio part it seems to be missing some things that I will need in the future like DSP for example. But thanks for the pointer to that.

Comment: Apart from the fact that treating an array of `void*` as an array of `SampleStereo16` being an odd thing to do, there's no guarantee that it's aligned properly. It's very likely that `void*`'s alignment is at least as strict as that of a struct containing to `int16_t`s, but the language doesn't guarantee it.

Comment: @Zuljin : I have been reading some stuff about pointers today and was still a little confused. The examples given by you and others here made me understand that I was trying to hard to understand it while the solutions are pretty obvious. Thanks for that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `buffer` is an array of pointers to `void`.  That is unusual.  Usually we declare a buffer as an array of `char` or `unsigned char` or `uint8_t` or some other byte-sized type:

```
char buffer[100000]; // data buffer
```

Anyway, the “correct” C++-style cast is `reinterpret_cast`:

```
sample = reinterpret_cast<SampleStereo16 *>(buffer);
```

On the other hand, you could just declare `buffer` as an array of `SampleStereo16` in the first place.  Then you don't need a cast at all:

```
SampleStereo16 buffer[6250];
SampleStereo16 *sample;

sample = buffer;
```

Comment: So in fact what I was doing is setting my data as addresses into those pointers? In fact what I did is not only unusual but a better description for what I did would be "stupid".

Comment: There's no guarantee that an array of `char` is properly aligned for type `SampleStereo16`. Creating an array of `SampleStereo16` neatly solves that problem.

Comment: @Keith : I am aware of that, but for that part I was relying on the fact that my buffer was an even multiple of SampleStereo16 and that the FMOD function used should only return whole PCM samples otherwise the soundfile must have been corrupt in the first place. The very first thing I tried was declaring an array of SampleStereo16 but I did `SampleStereo16 *buffer[6250];` and that gave me an error saying it has to be void, but now I understand what I did wrong. The concept of pointers can be pretty confusing when you're new to C++.

Comment: @DanielP: Type `SampleStereo16` likely requires 2-byte or 4-byte alignment. A `char[100000]` array will *probably* be aligned at an even address, but the required alignment for such an array is only 1 byte. Standalone objects are typically, but not necessarily, given stricter alignment, but on my system, given `struct foo {char c; char buf[100000];};`, I get `offsetof(struct foo, buf) == 1`

Answer (score 0):

You should use the sizeof operator to figure out how many samples were read. I.e., your byte array should be an even multiple of size(SampleStereo16).

You would then typically walk the byte array in chunks of that size. You malloc(sizeof(SampleStereo16)) to get each SampleStereo16* pointer, then memcpy that amount of data from your byte array and add it to your vector or array.

If you pack and unpack each array of your structs consistently that way, you should have no problems.

It's also very common to allocate the first few bytes in your serialized file to a version number of some sort, in case you decide to add more fields to your struct later, but it doesn't seem like that's your use case here, based on your entire code sample.